# Properly importing Apache nutch to eclipse EE juno using SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, svn, nutch

I have imported apache nutch from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/trunk/ through SVN on eclipse; however, the project I have imported has 10k+ java errors:

1. Some errors are due to source files being in a package different from what is specified in their source, (e.g. classes in java.org.apache... but it is declared in source that they should be in org.apache..., this is observed in many other packages)
2. Unimported classes, for example the Class "Context" is used in many of the classes however when looking at the import list, "Context" is not declared there.
3. Missing classes, though imported, classes still not resolved to a type, most probably because my imported project lacks many of the needed libraries such as hadoop,gora,witty,etc.
4. (Not familiar with this) Bound mismatch errors like: **The generic method createDataStore(Configuration, Class, Class) of type StorageUtils is not applicable for the arguments (Configuration, Class, Class). The inferred type WebPage is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter**

What is the correct way of importing a nutch through eclipse without encountering  the errors specified above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse

These should be followed to the "T" and it works fine.

Specially, pay attention to the manual configuration  of the build paths for the plugins.

You may also notice that some library dependancies are not set even after setting the build path,within certain plugins. .. you will need to manually add the ivey dependancies for these plugins into the build patch as well.